# very small icons in Android studio and Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, icons, toolbar

Just bought a laptop (zenbook ux302lg 1920x1080) and installed windows 8.1 on  it and I came across the problem in android studio and eclipse.

Icons and font got really bad scaling and are very small. Although I manage to do something about font (in settings) I just can't find any good solution for icons...

Any gurus in here that know how to fix it ?

Comment: Define "very small" please.

Comment: I would say half the size of the icons in my bookmarks bar (in chrome browser) if that helps...?